# Work done in submerging a weightless sphere, I am getting exactly half the correct answer, can someone point out my mistake!

Tags: calculus, physics

This is the question: A sphere of radius 0.4 m and having negligible weight is floating in a large freshwater lake. How much work is required to completely submerge the sphere? The density of
the water is 1000 kg/m3

My answer:

Imagine the position of the sphere when it is floating on the water and no force has been applied yet, we will cut this sphere into slices of height $dh$ that are parallel to the water surface.

Finding the work done on the bottom hemisphere: Consider a slice that is $h$ units below the center of the sphere, its radius (radius of the slice, not the sphere), is given by the Pythagoras theorem $$r=\sqrt{0.4^2-h^2}=\sqrt{0.16-h^2}$$

The Volume of this slice is $\pi r^2\hspace{1mm}dh=\pi \left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh$

Every slice will move down by 0.8m, but the slices will experience no force when they are moving in the air, a constant force proportional to their volume will act once they are in the water.

A slice that is $h$ units below the center, will spend $0.4-h$ meters in the air and $0.8-(0.4-h)=0.4+h$ meters in the water

So, the work done on this slice is $$W^*=F\cdot d=9.8\cdot 1000\pi\left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh\cdot (0.4+h)$$

Note that: $F=\rho g V$ ($\rho$ is density of water and $V$ is the volume displaced by the slice)

Integrate from 0 to 0.4, to get complete work done on the lower hemisphere

$$W=9800\pi \int_0^{0.4}(0.4+h)\left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh\longrightarrow\left(\text{Equation 1}\right)$$

Finding the work done on the upper hemisphere: Consider a slice that is $h$ units above the center of the sphere, its radius is $$r=\sqrt{0.4^2-h^2}=\sqrt{0.16-h^2}$$

Volume of this slice is $\pi r^2\hspace{1mm}dh=\pi\left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh$

A slice that is $h$ units above the center, will spend $0.4+h$ meters in the air and $0.8-(0.4-h)=0.4-h$ meters in the water

So, the work done on this slice is $$W^*=F\cdot d=9.8\cdot1000\pi \left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh\cdot (0.4-h)$$

Integrate from 0 to 0.4, to get complete work done on the lower hemisphere

$$W_2=9800\pi \int_0^{0.4}(0.4-h)\left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh\longrightarrow\left(\text{Equation 2}\right)$$

After adding $\left(\text{Equation 1}\right)$ and $\left(\text{Equation 2}\right)$, we get

$$W=W_1+W_2=9800\pi \int_0^{0.4}(0.4-h+0.4+h)\left(0.16-h^2\right)\hspace{1mm}dh$$

$$=0.8\cdot9800\pi\int_0^{0.4}0.16-h^2\hspace{1mm}dh$$

$$=0.8\cdot9800\pi\bigg[0.16h-\dfrac{h^3}{3}\bigg]_0^{0.4}$$

$$=0.8\cdot9800\pi\bigg[0.16\cdot0.4-\dfrac{0.4^3}{3}\bigg]-0\approx1051\text{ J}$$

The correct answer is obviously $\bigg[\dfrac{4}{3}\pi\cdot 0.4^3\cdot1000\bigg]\cdot9.8\cdot0.8\approx2102\text{ Joules}$

But I need to do this by using calculus because this is in a calculus textbook with very little physics background.

Comment: What you get by calculus seems right to me. I do not think $2102$ is correct. I think that should be $\frac{4}{3} \pi R^4 \rho \ g$.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you!, 2102 is not the correct answer